# Create a global sort method inside a .js file required inside main.js. Inside Component.vue :click call sort on a computed property. Is this possible?

Tags: vue.js

main.js

```
import Component from '/Component';
require('/file.js');
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   components: {
      Component
   }
});
```

file.js

```
sortComputedArray = function(field_name, direction, computedArray){
    computedArray.sort() //example instead of lodash.js
}
```

Component.vue

```
<template>
   <button :click="sortComputedArray('id', 'asc', computedArray)"></button>
</template>
export default {
   computed: {
       computedArray(){
          return this.new_array;
       }
   },
   data(){
      return{
        new_array: [associativeArrayWithIds]
      }
   }
}
```

This is the idea, but I am not sure how to declare that method in the .js file and how to pass the computed property array in order to use this method as a global filter in the future. Any ideas?

Comment: How about using mixins , it is standard with Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- The event handler shorthand is `@` like `@click`, not `:` like `:click`
- You are trying to sort a `computed` without cloning it first, which would mutate it.  Computeds are automatically calculated based on reactive data and should not be mutated.

I won't address those since your question is asking about importing/exporting.  You can import the helper function directly into any component.  But first you have to `export` it using [es6 module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) syntax from `file.js`:

```js
export const sortComputedArray = function(field_name, direction, computedArray){
    computedArray.sort() //example instead of lodash.js
}
```

Now it's ready to be imported in `Component.vue`.  You can use it anywhere in the component as `sortComputedArray`:

```html
<template>
   <button @click="sort"></button>
</template>

<script>
import { sortComputedArray } from './file.js';

export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    sort() {
      // This is called from the button, and it sorts the data array
      sortComputedArray('id', 'asc', this.new_array);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The onclick I wrote quickly. Since I shouldn't mutate the computed, I will try a different approach and let you know. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I am receiving the field_name, direction values in the export const sortComputedArray but I am unable to assign them to the data: inside my component.

Comment: Question:  do you want it to require a button click or do you want a computed to automatically sort your array using your external method?  It seems you are using a combination of both ideas.  It's also unclear where `associativeArrayWithIds` comes from or why it's wrapped in another array.

Comment: The is a v-for over a filtered computed property. The button calls the .js file method that should change the variable value reactively of that vue component, and the computed property then sorts the array.

Comment: But.. the external method *is* a sort.  So having it change the variable will sort it and then you want to sort it again in the computed?  Doesn't make sense.  I'll just show how to use the external method.  It sounds like there is no need for a button, just have a computed sort the array using the external method.

Comment: There is an already sorted array with the computed method which at the end uses lodash. Onclick i want to change the lodash field name and direction(asc,desc). Maybe the question before was vague, i hope it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: I'm sorry this question keeps changing, and it still sounds like you are trying to sort a computed array in a way that would mutate it, which is not allowed.  My goal was to show you how to use the external function in your component, hopefully you can see how this is done now.